# How to make numpy indexing more efficient and faster

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to preprocess my dataset to use for deep learning. I have a csv file that contains the data and I read it using pandas and try to preprocess it. The first column is a string and all the other columns are float. I want to use min max normalization for all columns with float.

```py
#Reading csv with pandas
metadatas=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dataset_dir,"metadata.csv"),header=None)
metadatas=np.array(metadatas)
metadatas_values=metadatas[:,1:]

#normalize the float datas
scaler=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(metadatas_values)
metadatas_scaled=scaler.transform(metadatas_values)

#Create dataframe to insert the string column ('filename') back to data and turn it back to array again
df_scaled=pd.DataFrame(metadatas_scaled)
df_scaled.insert(0,'filename',metadatas[:,0])
metadatas_scaled=np.array(df_scaled)

#Use for loop to index float columns based on string column'filename'
for filename in filenames:
    metadata=metadatas_scaled[np.where(metadatas_scaled==filename)[0]][0,1:]
```

I think my code is inefficient and slow to run when I have >30000 files. I think the most time consuming thing is indexing the array in the for loop. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use [inverted_index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) to store index for each filename (i.e. dictionary that maps: filename->idx)

Comment: thanks! that's a great idea.. will try it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit optimized code. The idea is to minimize allocations of new arrays and use groupby() instead of loop+indexing.

```py
# read file and set the first column as index
df = pd.read_csv(
    os.path.join(dataset_dir,"metadata.csv"), 
    header=None, 
    index_col=0
)

# scale all columns except index (our string column)
# + reuse index and column names from the original DataFrame
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(
    MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df.values), 
    index=df.index, 
    columns=df.columns
)

# group by index (our string column)
for metadata in df_scaled.groupby(level=0):
    # do smth with metadata
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! will try this once I get back to work on Monday